# Maximizing the total number of feasible constraints of a linear program

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, advice, np-complete

I have an optimization problem with $N$ **linear inequality constraints**  and $K$ **real valued** parameters (e.g. $0.2\alpha_1+0.5\alpha_2\geq 0$, $K=2$) and **no objective function**. Here $N$ is much larger than $K$ and not all constraints have to be satisfied. The question is the following:

> Find the parameters $\alpha_1,...,\alpha_K$ such that out of $N$ constraints maximum number of them ($M\leq N$) are satisfied.

Is this problem NP-Hard? What is the most effective way of solving such problems for large $N$ and $K$?

Comment: If you phrase it as $\min_{x,s} \{ ||s||_0 : Ax+s=b \}$, it is similar to the problem studied in [this paper](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/f629/5fd69d76d606f66cc15f58767a8161d60335.pdf).

Comment: @LinAlg that problem is a completey different one, as long as I understood. In my problem the parameter vector is real valued and there are no constraints for the choice of parameters. The only point is the total number of constraints that are satisfied. Out of all parameter vectors I need the one which will increase this number. A specific example is here: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/184194/maximax-optimization-over-a-particular-matrix

Comment: My phrasing of your problem seems correct to me. If $s_i=0$, constraint $i$ is satisfied. The objective maximizes the number of elements in $s$ that are $0$.

Comment: @LinAlg I roughly understood what you are saying. Two points: $1.$ I have inequality constraints. $2.$ I checked that paper and there is $L_2$ norm and sparse solution in terms of the parameters. I have neither of these things..

Comment: If there is no objective function, then there is nothing to optimize. If you consider a matrix form of the constraints, then maybe you want to remove redundant rows from the matrix (the ones that form a linear combination of other rows).

Comment: @NoChance there is something to optimize of course. It is the total number of constraints which hold. I can define this as an objective function. But this objective function is non-linear and solutions are pretty slow and problematic. I didnt get the connection between linearly independent rows and the total number of constraints which hold given the variables.

Comment: I see your point. I thought that some of the inequalities are redundant and you need to remove those redundant ones.

Comment: @LinAlg are you proposing one-norm minimization to approximate the solution?

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören not particularly, but it could give reasonable solutions

Answer (score 3):

This can be shown to be NP-hard by reduction from 0-1 ILP feasibility.  Take any 0-1 integer linear programming feasibility problem

$Ax=b$

$x \in \left\{ 0, 1 \right\}^{n}$

Where $A$ has $m$ rows and $n$ columns.

Relax the integrality constraint and add $2n$ additional constraints

$x_{i}=0, i=1, 2, \ldots, n$

$x_{i}=1, i=1, 2, \ldots, n$

Now, the 0-1 ILP is feasible if and only if you can satisfy $m+n$ constraints in the real system of equations.

Comment: I’ve used equality constraints, but any equality constraint can be replaced by a pair of inequalities.

Comment: Which algorithm may be the most suitable to solve this problem? I have a person by person approach in mind but I am sure there should be more effective ones..

Comment: You can formulate your problem as a mixed integer linear programming problem with one 0-1 variable for each of the original inequality constraints using the "Big-M technique" for turning the constraint on or off by whether the variable is 0 or 1.  Whether it will be practical to solve the resulting MILP will depend a lot on the size of the problem.

Comment: Okey. As long as I understood you talking about the same method which @LinAlg described in his comment. The objective function would then be the $L_0$ norm of the related vector of zeros and ones.

Comment: $x_i=0$ and $x_i=1$ for the same indexes? That sounds strange to me.

Comment: Having $x_{i}=0$ and $x_{i}=1$ in the constraints is useful in this case, because no more than one of the two constraints can be satisfied, and we're counting the number of satisfied constraints.

Comment: @SeyhmusGüngören this is not the same method that LinAlg discussed.  He/she is proposing to use one-norm minimization to approximate the solution rather than integer programming.

Comment: Ok, so constraints are linear, parameters are real and integer and the objective function is the $L_0$-norm. What solver should I use to solve this thing? I have $40000$ inequality constraints and each inequality has one different integer parameter (on-off parameter as you said), and $500$ real valued parameters, the same $500$ parameters for each inequality. I must find $40000$ $0-1$-valued variables and $500$ real variables such that $L_0$ norm of the integer variable vector is minimized. The objective function is non-linear. I cannot solve this in Mathematica with LinearProgamming.

Comment: Where should I solve this little behemoth?

Comment: The integer programming approach probably won't work well with 40,000 constraints.